# Values inserted twice in Mysql PHP

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2

```
function disburseby_cash($branch,$mode,$date,$amount){

    if ($amount>0){
        $sql="INSERT INTO `pettycash_deliver` SET `branch_id`='$branch',`petCashDel_mode`='$mode',`petCashdel_dt`='$date',`petCashdel_amt`='$amount', `branch_status`='Y',`petCashdel_akBrnch`='N' ";
        return $fin_res=(parent :: selectquery($sql)) ? "OK":"NO";   
    }else{
        return "fail";
    }
}
```

This is my code. When I was try to add some data.. It will inserted double         time. This problem will occurs on some time only.. Kindly give the solution...

Thanks in advance....

Comment: `return (parent :: selectquery($sql)) ? "OK":"NO";` use this instead of  `return $fin_res=(parent :: selectquery($sql)) ? "OK":"NO";`

Comment: because you have not created a unique index

Comment: i think you are mixing update and insert query

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because `$_GET` data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

**NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly in your query.

Comment: Note: Spacing out things like `parent::selectquery(...)` is probably a bad idea. Keep those together.

Comment: But this problem will occurs on some times only... Not every insert operation....

Comment: It could be that your function is getting called twice. Have you checked the rest of the code? Try debugging it by adding some logging in your function and checking how many times it's getting called